# Evaluating the Limit of the Integral of $(1-x/n)^n$

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I wanted to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty (1-x/n)^n \, dx$ converges
using Lebesgue integrable techniques. (I wolfram'd this to see that this converges to $+1$).

What I have tried so far:

I tried to use DCT but ran into a problem: I know that it is possible to bound $(1-x/n)^n$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$, however bounding this by an
integrable function on $x\geq n$ is quite hard, I don't think it is possible.

My next thought was to define $f_n(x) := (1-x/n)^n$ if $x<n$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. I know these $f_n$'s converge to the same function as the sequence $\{(1-x/n)^n\}$ but I'm not quite sure how I would show that,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n (1-x/n)^n \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty (1-x/n)^n \, dx$$
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: show that $(f_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of functions, and use Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: This does not converge, it oscillates between $\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Did you mean $\int_0^n (1-x/n)^ndx$?

Comment: What about if we take the sequence in absolute value?

Comment: Note that $\int_{0}^{\infty} |1-x/n|^ndx = \infty$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: (Assuming you really mean to integrate $\int_0^n$): The easiest way to evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^n (1-x/n)^ndx$ is to directly compute the integral for each $n$ and then take $n\rightarrow\infty$.  Another way (by LDC) is to first prove that $e^{-x}$ is a valid bounding function over $x \geq 0$.